# SQL select from two tables (user have max car)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables.

```
USER: ID | NAME_USER

CAR: ID | ID_USER | NAME_CAR
```

I want print user which have max car, how can i do this?

My try (not working):

```
SELECT `NAME_USER`, NAME_CARFROM FROM USER, CAR
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be this

```
select  user.name_user 
from user 
inner join  (select id_user,  count(*) num 
     from car group by id_user order by num desc limit 1) as t on t.id_user  = user.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Join the tables, count the number of cars per user, and show the one with the highest number.

```
SELECT name_user
FROM user
JOIN car
GROUP BY id_user
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

If multiple users have the same max number of cars, this will pick one of them arbitrarily.